# Finding bolts to attach mudguard on Trek 4500

Tags: fenders, trek

I bought a couple of plastic mudguards a while ago but the bolts that came with it don't go through on my Trek 4500 mountain bike. I wonder how to get the bolt specifications for where the mudguard attaches to this bike? Sorry if my terminology is off.

Comment: Try different screws until you find the ones that fit.

Comment: Are you able to measure the diameter of the mounting holes in the frame, and the bolts you do have? There might be some common sizes and it could narrow things down

Comment: Which holes? The larger ones in the brake bridge and fork, or the small eyelets near the dropouts?

Comment: Wrt: trying different screws, I need to know which ones to get. Are there specifications for this? The larger ones in the brake bridge and the fork is what I am looking for. The screws that came with the fenders did not fit.

Comment: a photo with a tape measure or even better a caliper (vernier) held next to the hole(s) would be helpful